# ЦИКЛ инкремента HEX

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите какие способы есть написать вот такое на Python 3.x

Есть начальное и конечное значение в HEX 64 длинны
Нужно чтобы комбинировалось
Например

```
low  = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

high = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140
```

Запускаем скрипт и он начинает делать следующее

> ```
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000070000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009000000000
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b00000000000
> 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c000000000000
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d0000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000
> 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000500000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000070000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000009000000000000000000000000
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000a0000000000000000000000000
> ```

и т.д. 
до

> ```
> fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140
> ```

то есть справа налево прибавляет по 1 значению

Получится цикл, подскажите варианты написания, хотя бы с чего начать.

Примеры кода приветствуются, спасибо.

Comment: Сделать цикл от 0 до 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140, значения приводить к hex, добивая слева 0 до нужной длины: `for i in range(0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140 + 1):` дальше вы приводите `i` к hex

Comment: понял, спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: Написал работает, теперь появилась необходимость сделать обратное, то есть чтобы начиналось 
100000000000000000000000000000
200000000000000000000000000000
300000000000000000000000000000
а00000000000000000000000000000
a10000000000000000000000000000

Comment: слева направо по +1 какие есть примеры?

Comment: Вы молодец :), добавьте, тогда вашу реализацию в ответ. Для обратного используйте `reversed(range(<ваше значение>))`

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь) удачи)

Answer (score 0):

```
#ЦИКЛ инкремента HEX

for i in range(0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140 + 1):
        hex = "%064x" % i

        print(hex)
```

Comment: Зачем while True?

Comment: Точно, спасибо за замечания. Забыл убрать, так как у меня целый код из 70 строк, изначально он там должен быть, но я думаю это роли не играет, работу все равно свою делает)